# Find out if at a certain position in a jTextPane there is a specific char [java]

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane, java-6

I'm writing an action for a jTextPane's getActionMap that when I type ')' IF at the Caret Position there's a ')' the action overwrite the symbol, ELSE it normally types ')'. 
This is the code:

```
    Action action1 = new AbstractAction() {


                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    char bracket = ')';
                    try {
                            int position = jTextPane1.getCaretPosition();
                            if (jTextPane1.getDocument.getText(position,1)== ")") {
                                jTextPane1.getDocument().remove(position, 1);
                                jTextPane1.getDocument().insertString(position, ")", null);
                            } else {
                                jTextPane1.getDocument().insertString(position, ")", null);

                            }

                   } catch (Exception e1) {}
                }

            };


            String key1 = "typed )";
            jTextPane1.getInputMap().put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(key1), key1);
            jTextPane1.getActionMap().put(key1, action1);
        }
```

I can't understand why, even if the the boolean of the 'if' is true, it does not go in the if way. Can you help me?

Comment: Have you thought about using a `DocumentFilter`?

Comment: No, I did not. I thought that the usage of KeyStroke was good for this kind of task. How can I use the DocumentFilter here?

Comment: `jTextPane1.toString()`?  I'm surprised you've not run into a index out of bounds exception yet.  I think you meant to use `jTextPane1.getText()`

Comment: What happens if the OP pastes text into the component?  The key binding won't be notified.  A `DocumentFilter` will allow you to process changes that are "going" to occur to a `Document` before they are actually committed to it (and change them)

Comment: I edited the question. I changed  jTextPane1.toString() with jTextPane1.getDocument().getText(position,1) but still not working.

Comment: I'm sorry to ask but..can you show me an example of DocumentFilter for this problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107078/discussion-between-pino-and-madprogrammer).

Comment: First off `getText(position,1)` returns a blank `String`, because there's nothing there (the caret has moved position), you'll need to use `getText(position - 1,1)`

Comment: I don't recommend using a DocumentFilter. You should stick with the KeyBindings so your code is consistent. That is you already have a binding for the "(" key. So now you add a binding for the ")". Having similar logic in two different places is confusing. Using the KeyBindings allows you to further customize other keys if needed. When you use the key bindings you will also have access to the source of the event which can be helpful. I still don't understand the reason for this. Why can't I have "))" together in my source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> even if the the boolean of the 'if' is true, it does not go in the if way

Did you do any basic debugging to see what is happening?

```
if (jTextPane1.getDocument.getText(position,1)== ")") {
```

The problem is you should NOT be using "==" for object comparison. It will never be true.

You should be using the `equals(...)` method:

This is easily verified by simplifying the code and added debug statements.

```
String text = jTextPane1.getDocument().getText(position, 1); 
System.out.println(text);

if (text.equals(")"))
{
    System.out.println("matches");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("doesn't match");
}
```

With the above simple code you can easily verify if the text value is what you expect. Don't write complex statements with multiple methods. Simplyfying the code into multiple statements makes it much easier to debug.

Answer (score 2):

So, this is a simple example of a `DocumentFilter` which, when the user tries to add the `)` character, the filter checks to see if the character before it is also a `)` and basically rejects the update

```
public class TestPane extends JPanel {

    public TestPane() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JTextPane tp = new JTextPane();
        add(new JScrollPane(tp));

        ((AbstractDocument) tp.getDocument()).setDocumentFilter(new DocumentFilter() {
            @Override
            public void insertString(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, String string, AttributeSet attr) throws BadLocationException {
                super.insertString(fb, offset, string, attr);
            }

            @Override
            public void remove(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length) throws BadLocationException {
                System.out.println("Remove");
                super.remove(fb, offset, length);
            }

            @Override
            public void replace(DocumentFilter.FilterBypass fb, int offset, int length, String text, AttributeSet attrs) throws BadLocationException {
                if (offset > 0) {
                    String before = fb.getDocument().getText(offset - 1, 1);
                    if (!(")".equals(before) && ")".equals(text))) {
                        super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attrs);
                    }
                } else {
                    super.replace(fb, offset, length, text, attrs);
                }
            }

        });
    }

}
```

While I could get it to add a `)` when the character been inserted was a `(`, it moved the caret to after the `)` which wasn't particularly helpful